# Remove trailing slash using .htaccess except for home / landing page

Tags: .htaccess

I've successfully modified my .htaccess file to remove trailing slashes on most pages but I'm wondering how to exempt my home page/directory?  For example:

domain.com/test/ successfully redirects to domain.com/test

HOWEVER, when I hit my domain it will append the root document

domain.com/ redirects to domain.com/index.php

Is there a condition that I can add to ignore root url trailing slash so that it doesn't attempt to remove the trailing slash and add my default script? Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK. After a bunch of trial and error I answered my own question.

The third line denotes that there has to be something in the URI in order to perform the redirect thus not redirecting if the url just contains the initial slash.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Instead of `http://www.domain.com/$1` you can use `http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` better. So user don't need to edit that line and make possible errors.

Comment: @YH's solution does not work for websites in subdirectories (nor for localhost, which cannot have `www.` before itself). So e.g. `localhost/web1/page1/` is redirected in a wrong way to `www.localhost/page1`.

Answer (score 17):

Redirects request for all URLs ending in a `/` except for the root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$ $1
```

Comment: also handles http / https equally

Comment: I have add this code in htaccess file. Its working fine.
But My css files are not load.

Comment: This redirect rule only targets URLs that end in a "/". I do not think it could be affecting CSS files. I am using this code on a live site, and all files load correctly.

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```