# Remove trailing slash using .htaccess in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I'm looking for a way to remove trailing slash for all WordPress URL's.

I found similar answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167539/remove-trailing-slash-using-htaccess-except-for-home-landing-page) but it doesn't work when there's WordPress .htaccess rules before.

Here is my current WordPress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If it doesn't work try this one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteRule (.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should NOT update anything between the #BEGIN Wordpress block in .htaccess!

Comment: @Yashvit Saying that without giving any viable solution is useless.

Comment: Permalinks? The other answer? Do I need to repeat?

Comment: The directive that removes the trailing slash needs to go _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. (As @Yashvit pointed out, you should not edit the section between the `# BEGIN/END WordPress` comment markers because WP itself tries to maintain this code block and any custom directives are likely going to get overwritten. This is WP specific. Ordinarily, you would put the directive exactly as posted, unless you need to access directories (unlikely) then you need an additional _condition_ to exclude directories.)

Answer (score 41):

It might be as simple as go to settings > permalinks in the wp admin and remove the trailing slash at the input box for custom structure

Comment: So simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best and simple solution. it worked for me. I don't like messing with .htaccess file unless it's necessary

Comment: Awesome! So much easier and less stressful than modifying .htaccess! I was skeptical that it would be that easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Here are the steps to remove trailing slashes site-wide. If you simply wish to remove the trailing slashes on posts only, skip to **Step 2**.

### Important Things To Consider

- In `.htaccess`, the code between lines `# BEGIN WordPress` & `# END WordPress` [may get reset by WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257217). Avoid changing code between those lines.
- Forcing removal of trailing slashes, causes a [loop in example.com/wp-admin](https://moz.com/community/q/how-to-force-wordpress-to-remove-trailing-slashes). You can avoid the issue by excluding directories `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

The following solution addresses those issues.

## Step 1 - Update /.htaccess file

Add the following code before the `# BEGIN WordPress` line in your /.htaccess file. This redirects URLs with trailing slashes to URLs with no trailing slashes.

```
# Remove trailing slashes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

## Step 2 - Update Permalinks

As others have pointed out, you must also update your Permalinks (Settings -> Permalinks) to Custom Structure, and remove the trailing slash there. It removes the trailing slash on all your posts.
[image]

Comment: Should be considered as an accepted answer because of the begin wordpress thing! Well done!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this trailing slash in WordPress URL problem, log in to your website admin panel -> go to Setting Tab -> click on Permalinks under Settings. It will open a page something like the below screen:

Now, check to verify the setting you have opted for the website URL structure. Make sure that you are not leaving a trailing slash in the URL structure.
https://blog.techblogsearch.com/2018/11/29/guide-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-wordpress-url

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch .htaccess manually as it is sensitive.
Do the following steps.

1. Go to Settings -> Permalinks and  Change the custom structure and remove the ending Slash (/)

[image]

2. Go to tools -> Permalink manager and then Settings tab.

a. Under Settings tab click on Redirect Settings then  Enable **Trailing slashes redirect** by clicking checkbox.

[image]

b. Under settings tab click on General settings then Choose Trailing slashes options from drop down

[image]