# WordPress Trailing Slash

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

WordPress adds trailing slash to each url as per permalink settings.

/%postname%/

So if you browse **www.mysite.com/about-us** you will be redirected to **www.mysite.com/about-us/**

Is it possible to disable this redirect so that the page is served with and without the trailing slash.

Comment: have you checked your permalink & htaccess file

Comment: So why not try remove the ending `/` in permalink ? Should not it work?

Comment: Please text htaccess code

Answer (score 4):

change permalink  `/%postname%/` to `/%postname%`

[image]

**Right below the RewriteEngine On line, add:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

[Moreinfo htaccess code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for your reply, I can change it but then Wordpress will start redirecting urls the other way, i.e. urls with trailing slash will be redirected to urls without trailing slash. Clients wants both url to be viewable with and without trailing slash and no redirect

Answer (score 2):

You can update your .htaccess file with following rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)/$ http://your_domain_name/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change .htaccess rules, defined by WordPress. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558234/remove-trailing-slash-using-htaccess-in-wordpress) might hepls you.