# How to resolve redirection issue with "/" URL in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks, google-search-console, trailing-slash

We are facing a page with a Redirection issue with the "/" URL. Our website structure is "https://www.example.com/tableau-consulting-services.html" But some all our landing page and blog pages are getting issues with this type of URL " https://www.example.com/tableau-consulting-services.html/ " in google search console.

Such type of "/" is not represented on our HTaccess file and Root Directory. Even proper canonicals have been set and we have not added such URLs in the sitemap.xml file as well. We have also blocked "*HTML/ " in the robots.txt file and even the htaccess file as well.

Please do suggest us what next we can do.

Comment: What are your permalink settings?   What is the code in your htaccess?  It is very hard to help you debug this if you don't show us your code.

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048512/1145388 if you haven't already implemented that.