# .htacess redirect to remove '/' at the end of URL?

Tags: .htaccess

For some reason some links create slashes at the end of urls. I discovered the same link in a different device can or cannot add a slash at the end of the URL.

Due to my htaccess structuring I sometimes get errors if the URLs have slashes. Is there a way to remove them from URLs with htaccess?

EG:

```
example.com/s/
```

instantly redirects to:

```
example.com/s
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove trailing slash using .htaccess except for home / landing page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167539/remove-trailing-slash-using-htaccess-except-for-home-landing-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217445/969967) gave this answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This do the job and you don't need to specify the domain :

`RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]`